# compile HTML5 game files to exe

Tags: javascript, html

How would I compile a HTML5 game to an `.exe` so people cant mess with it. My game has no external library's if that helps, and not all of it hast to be compiled just HTML files.

Comment: with that http://nwjs.io/, you can

Comment: Turning the game into an exe won't stop people from messing with it.

Comment: I know but it will less tempting

Comment: But people with an Apple (me) can't play your game anymore.

Comment: how do you think to get an .exe cross platform game ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be cross platform, you should keep it as HTML5 and javascript. to *help* prevent people "messing with it" you could [obfuscate](http://www.jsobfuscate.com/) the javascript.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is:

1) Download Visual Studio Express Edition(Because it's free).

2) File -> New Project -> Windows Forms Application.

3) Load your current HTML into it.

4) Add WebBrowser control to your project.

5) Deploy your application(Build -> Publish).

Note: The WebBrowser Control use IE by-default. Take a look at this alternative as well.

**update**:

if you want for android , IOS , windows phone ,blackberry you can use phonegap. but you need to work on performance depend on game you have

Comment: But I want it to be cross platform

Comment: If cross-platform, do not ask for an exe:)

Comment: if you want for android , IOS , windows phone ,blackberry you can use **phonegap**. but you need to work on performance depend on game you have

Comment: @thatguy please accept this answer if you find it useful :)

Comment: I wonder how hard is it for people to mess with it this way.